# how to setContent (python)

Tags: python

I have a problem. I don't know how to setContent and getContent twice in one class. Is this even possible? Thank you.
Here is the example with one set and get...

```
     if self.msg:
            msgContent = int(self.msg.getContent())

            if msgContent < brojka:

                print "1:" % msgContent



                self.msg = spade.ACLMessage.ACLMessage()
                primatelj = spade.AID.aid(
                    name='player@127.0.0.1',
                    addresses=['xmpp://player@127.0.0.1'])
                self.msg.setPerformative('inform')
                self.msg.addReceiver(primatelj)
                self.msg.setContent('More')
                self.msg.setOntology('reaction')
                self.myAgent.send(self.msg)
                self.msg = None
```

How to set and get two times with different content? Is this possible. For example(but it's not working):

if self.msg:
                msgContent = int(self.msg.getContent())

```
            if msgContent < brojka:

                print "1:" % msgContent
                num=1+1


                self.msg = spade.ACLMessage.ACLMessage()
                primatelj = spade.AID.aid(
                    name='player@127.0.0.1',
                    addresses=['xmpp://player@127.0.0.1'])
                self.msg.setPerformative('inform')
                self.msg.addReceiver(primatelj)

                self.msg.setContent(num)
                self.msg.setContent('More')


                self.msg.setOntology('reaction')
                self.myAgent.send(self.msg)
                self.msg = None
```

Comment: What is your problem ? Where does it fail ? Please also give some context. You can call both methods consecutively if you want to, nothing wrong with that. (Also, show the full code, we don't know what `spade` or `brojka` is)

Comment: what are your errors? what are your expected results?

Comment: Do you mean _getters and setters_? In python those aren't normal used

Comment: Program is working, I just want to set and get more contents in one class. But don't know how... Here I just set 'More' ang getContent from another class

Comment: Spade is Smart Python multi-Agent Development Environment

Comment: what exactly is `self.msg`? what you could do it make self.msg a dict, and use keys to add more content?

Comment: http://spade.gti-ia.dsic.upv.es/manuals/html-chunk/spade.basicagents.agentmodel.communication.html